Play the next video when the first video finishes playing, and repeat the video slider cycle
I have the code below. I don't know how to play the next video when the first video finishes playing and repeat the slider video cycle when the entire video has finished playing. Please help me.
Below is the code I
HTML:
     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="swiper-blur"></div>
                                <div class="swiper-video-blur">
                                    <video class="video" auutoplay muted  style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; cursor: pointer;" poster="https://i.imgur.com/GTJB1xh.jpeg" src="https://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/34123252/preview/stock-footage-coworkers-discussing-in-the-future-of-their-company-over-several-charts-and-graphs-business.mp4"></video>
                                </div> 
<div class="swiper-video-blur">
<video class="video" muted autoplay style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; cursor: pointer;" poster="https://i.imgur.com/fR5sk7O.jpeg" src="https://ak1.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/25348301/preview/stock-footage--business-new-customers-sale-and-people-concept-thousands-of-people-formed-qr-code-crowd-flight.webm"></video>
                                </div>  

CSS
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-big .swiper-slide .banner {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 36vw;
    min-height: 193px;
   /* max-height: 540px;*/
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    filter: blur(0px);
}

.swiper-big .swiper-slide .banner::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, .2);
    pointer-events: none;
}

.swiper-big {
    min-height: 180px;
    /*max-height: 540px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    /* border-radius: 8px; */
}

.swiper-big img {
    width: 97%;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.swiper-blur {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0 40px 51px #1a1c1f;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(20,20,20,0) 1%,rgba(20,20,20,.7) 100%);
}
.swiper-video-blur {
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
}


JS
  const swiper_option1 = {

       
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true
        },
        spaceBetween: 0,
        on: {
            transitionStart: function() {
                $('.swiper-volume').addClass('fa-volume-high');
                $('.swiper-volume').removeClass('fa-volume-xmark');
                var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(videos, function(video) {
                    video.pause();
                    video.style.display = 'none';
                    video.muted = true;
                });
            },
            init: function() {
                var activeIndex = this.activeIndex;
                const silder_active = this.slides[activeIndex];
                const video_blur = $(silder_active).find('.swiper-video-blur video')[0];
                if (!video_blur) return;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    video_blur.style.display = 'block';
                    video_blur.play();
                }, 3000);
            },
            transitionEnd: function() {
                var activeIndex = this.activeIndex;
                const silder_active = this.slides[activeIndex];
                const video_blur = $(silder_active).find('.swiper-video-blur video')[0];
                if (!video_blur) return;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    video_blur.style.display = 'block';
                    video_blur.play();
                }, 3000);
            },
        }
    }
    if (isMobileDevice()) {
        swiper_option1.autoplay = {
            delay: 3000
        }
    }
    const swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper-big', swiper_option1); 

i tried what i found on google and it doesn't work, i hope someone can help me, thank you all

Your </div> make no sense, please try to create a [mcve].


Listen to the media element's "ended" event and then run sw.nextSlide()
Use MediaElement.load() or elVideo.pause(); elVideo.currentTime = 0; to reset all other (non-active) videos
To match the slide element to the current realIndex you could get the slide element's index from its dataset attribute
Use loop: true to create the infinite loop



const handleSwiperVideo = (sw) => {
  sw.slides.forEach((elSlide) => {
    const isActive = +elSlide.dataset.swiperSlideIndex === sw.realIndex;
    const elVideo = elSlide.querySelector("video");
    if (isActive) {
      elVideo.play();
      elVideo.addEventListener("ended", () => {
        sw.slideNext();
      }, {once: true});
    } else {
      elVideo.pause();
      elVideo.currentTime = 0;
    }
  });
};

const swiperOptions = {
  loop: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true
  },
  on: {
    init: function() {
      handleSwiperVideo(this);
    },
    transitionEnd: function() {
      handleSwiperVideo(this);
    },      
  }
};

const swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper-big', swiperOptions);
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-video-blur video {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<div class="swiper swiper-big">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-blur"></div>
      <div class="swiper-video-blur">
        Slide 1
        <video class="video" muted poster="https://i.imgur.com/GTJB1xh.jpeg" src="https://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/34123252/preview/stock-footage-coworkers-discussing-in-the-future-of-their-company-over-several-charts-and-graphs-business.mp4"></video>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-blur"></div>
      <div class="swiper-video-blur">
        Slide 2
        <video class="video" muted poster="https://i.imgur.com/GTJB1xh.jpeg" src="https://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/34123252/preview/stock-footage-coworkers-discussing-in-the-future-of-their-company-over-several-charts-and-graphs-business.mp4"></video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>




Oh thank you very much, your method worked, but if behind the video slider there is only an image but no video, then run the next image for about 3 seconds and then continue the slider, what should I do? Hope you can help, thank you very much.
and I want the image to appear for 3 seconds before playing the video

@ĐứcNguyễn it's not clear from the HTML you provided what IMG you're talking about.

With your example code above, is there a way to add pagination under the slider? Because I'm new to Swiper, I don't know much. I hope you can help me.
